# while filtering datatable server side Cannot resolve keyword 'priority' into field. Choices are: eventname, id, key, timestamp

Tags: django, filter, datatable

I'm using django-rest-framework-datatables to filtering/pagination/sorting datatable when using rest-framework,
it's working correctly with all fields except one, it's show error "Cannot resolve keyword 'priority' into field. Choices are: eventname, id, key"
i think that the problem is: this field not appear in database table

model

```
class CachedEvent(models.Model):
  key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
  eventname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   @property
   def priority(self):
      eventtype, created = EventType.objects.get_or_create(
        eventname=self.eventname
      )
     return eventtype.priority
```

viewSet:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   queryset = CachedEvent.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CachedEventSerializer
```

serializer:

```
class CachedEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 id = serializers.CharField(source='original_id')

 class Meta:
    model = CachedEvent
    fields = ['key', 'timestamp', 'id', 'eventname', 'priority']
```

can help me please

Answer (score 0):

Actually priority is not your model field, it's property. so that's why you get the error.
you have to add priority explicitly to your serializer fields.

```
class CachedEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 id = serializers.CharField(source='original_id')
 priority = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

 class Meta:
    model = CachedEvent
    fields = ['key', 'timestamp', 'id', 'eventname', 'priority']
```

Comment: serializers.ReadOnlyField() show same error "Cannot resolve keyword 'priority' into field. Choices are: eventname, id, key, timestamp" 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
serializers.Field() before the datatable load it is  show error "Field.to_representation() must be implemented for field priority"

Comment: how about to add source attribute? try to use source with ReadOnlyField() and pass the model property. @splinter.cell

Comment: It is redundant to specify `source='priority'` on field 'ReadOnlyField' in serializer 'CachedEventSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.